# Array of objects and i want to return true if any key value pair in the object is duplicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am fairly new to JS, I am struggling with a problem where there is an array of objects and i want to return true if any key value pair in the object is duplicate

```
var lookupValues = [{"key":"xiomi","value":"phone","id":1},{"key":"samsung","value":"tab",id:2},{"key":"blackberry","value":"phone","id":3},{"key":"xiomi","value":"tab","id":4},{"key":"asus","value":"phone",id:5}]}
```

Since key: "Xiomi" came twice so function should return true

i tried using lodash functions

```
var uniqueLookup =_uniqBy(lookupValues,'key')
if(_.isEqual(uniqueLookup, lookup)) return true
```

works but i guess i am missing something

Comment: You could implement this by using Set. You could iterate the list, check if key exists in the set and add key to set. 

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can do this in VanillaJs.

Set is a new data structure that JavaScript got in ES6. It’s a collection of unique values. We put into that the list of property values we get from using map(), which how we used it will return this array:

`[xiomi,Samsung,blackberry,xiomi,asus]`

Passing through Set, we’ll remove the duplicates i.e `xiomi` and at last `...` is the spread operator, which will expand the `Set` values into an array.

Now if length of this new array is equal to your `lookupValues.length` then it has no duplicates else duplicates are present.

```js
var lookupValues = [{"key":"xiomi","value":"phone","id":1},{"key":"samsung","value":"tab",id:2},{"key":"blackberry","value":"phone","id":3},{"key":"xiomi","value":"tab","id":4},{"key":"asus","value":"phone",id:5}]

const isDuplicate = (lookupValues) => !([...new Set(lookupValues.map(obj => obj.key))].length === lookupValues.length)

console.log(isDuplicate(lookupValues))
```

Comment: for me i just use Set.prototype.size property to get the quantity of items inside the newly create Set of keys and compare it with previous array length.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Compare the length of the array to the array shortened by checking if the key is unique.

```js
var lookupValues = [{"key":"xiomi","value":"phone","id":1},{"key":"samsung","value":"tab",id:2},{"key":"blackberry","value":"phone","id":3},{"key":"xiomi","value":"tab","id":4},{"key":"asus","value":"phone",id:5}];
console.log(_.uniqBy(lookupValues,"key").length !== lookupValues.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a vanilla Javascript code snippet with es6 `Set` object.

```
var lookupValues = [{"key":"xiomi","value":"phone","id":1},{"key":"samsung","value":"tab",id:2},{"key":"blackberry","value":"phone","id":3},{"key":"xiomi","value":"tab","id":4},{"key":"asus","value":"phone",id:5}]
const keys = lookupValues.map((v) => v.key)
const keySetSize = new Set(keys).size
const hasDuplicate = keys.length > keySetSize
console.log(hasDuplicate)
```